# Draw a centered line on Grid whose width is set automatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have seen several similar questions to this, but no solution works for me, probably because my Grid is set to `Stretch` . This is the result I am trying to achieve. Basically, I have one Grid and I'd like to draw an X-Axis line( like in the picture at the end of this question).

**My XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF4A70F1">
```

**My CodeBehind**

```
        Line XAxis = new Line();
        XAxis.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        XAxis.StrokeThickness = 1;

        XAxis.X1 = 0;
        XAxis.X2 = MainGrid.RenderSize.Width;
        XAxis.Y1 = MainGrid.RenderSize.Height / 2;
        XAxis.Y2 = MainGrid.RenderSize.Height / 2;

        MainGrid.Children.Add(XAxis);
```

**My Problem**

I 'd like this line to span the whole window, even if I resize/maximize the window. However, the calculations above for X2,Y1,Y2 don't work( all evaluate to 0, hence NO LINE shown) , whether I use `ActualSize`or  `*RenderSize*` . Can someone please point out how to fix that? Thank you
[image: to achieve]

Comment: When is your code executed? You would at least have to adjust the line endpoints when your window is resized, perhaps in a [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged.aspx) handler, or bind their x and y values to the Grid's size.

Comment: this is rightafter  InitializeComponent(); .but atleast i should see a line upon startup? no?

Comment: No, the window width and height are 0 in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XAML creates a vertically centered line that stretches horizontally:

```
<Grid>
    <Line HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Black"
          X2="{Binding ActualWidth,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}"/>
</Grid>
```